# How to reference an id from external js file

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a followup question.  I finally was able to get the prompt loop to work in the js function.  but I would like for it to show the answers (vars) that are inputted back on the main html.  I created a container for the list and then created `<p>` ids so that I could use

```
document.getElementById('emp'+loopct).innerHTML=inName;
```

to show the item in the browser. But it seems that "document" does not reference the html document (I notice the browser is dimmed in the background).  I will include the html and then the external script.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/payroll.css" />

<title>Payroll System</title>


<script type="text/javascript" >
var emps = new Array();
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<h1>Jackson Payroll System</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="inputEmp()">Click here to enter employees</button>

<div class="empContainer">
<p id=emp0> </p>
<p id=emp1> </p>
<p id=emp2> </p>
<p id=emp3> </p>
<p id=emp4> </p>
<p id=emp5> </p>
<p id=emp6> </p>
<p id=emp7> </p>
<p id=emp8> </p>
<p id=emp9> </p>
<p id=emp10> </p>
<p id=emp11> </p>
<p id=emp12> </p>
<p id=emp13> </p>
<p id=emp14> </p>
<p id=emp15> </p>
<p id=emp16> </p>
<p id=emp17> </p>
<p id=emp18> </p>
<p id=emp19> </p>
<p id=emp20> </p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/payroll.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>


function inputEmp() {
var inName = "";
var loopCt = 0
var tArray = new Array();

while (inName != "-1") 
{
    inName = prompt("Please enter your name (enter -1 to finish)","Employee Name");
if (inName == "-1")  { break; }
if (inName==null || inName=="")
    {
    alert("Blank names are not allowed.  To exit enter '-1'.");
    } 
else
    tArray[loopCt++] = inName;
    document.getElementById('emp'+loopct).innerHTML=inName;
{

}
}
return tArray;
}
```

Comment: You have an empty `{}` block where the else code should be.

Comment: "But it seems that "document" does not reference the html document (I notice the browser is dimmed in the background)." - what in the world are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
document.getElementById('emp'+loopct).innerHTML=inName;
```

You've used the variable `loopct`, but your loop counter is actually called `loopCt`. Case is significant in Javascript.

Comment: Wow, rookie mistake.  I hate the stupid one.  That fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, how do I input an Enter into the comments.  Everytime I try it closes the comment.

Comment: I don't like the spacing between the paragraphs.  I would prefer to use <br> but I would not be able to put an ID on it?  Is there a way around this?  Or a better way?

Comment: I am referring to:  <p id=emp0> </p>
<p id=emp1> </p>
<p id=emp2> </p>
<p id=emp3> </p>

Comment: @jjac68 I don't think you can insert line breaks in comments.

Comment: @jjac - we're off-topic for the question now, but a couple of options: change the spacing between paragraphs with CSS - use a class if appropriate, or think about using a table and add an id to the `<td>` elements

Answer (score 0):

you script isnt inside `<script>` tags.

your variable is called `loopCt` not `loopct`

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`document.getElementById('emp'+loopct).innerHTML=inName;`

`loopct` needs to be `loopCt` since JavaScript variables are case-sensitive.